Using assignment operator inside a while loop throws a syntax error
I was attempting a leetcode problem. Here I had to count the number of steps until the variable num is equal to 0. Here is my code:
class Solution:
    def numberOfSteps(self, num: int) -> int:
        step = 0
        while num != 0:
            num //= 2 if not num%2 else num -= 1
            step += 1
        return step

Here is the error from the console output:
  File "/home/syswraith/main.py", line 3
    num //= 2 if not num%2 else num -= 1
                                    ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What am I doing wrong?

That's nothing to do with the loop, you can't have two ((augmented) assignment) statements in one line anywhere. You'd have to do e.g. num = num // 2 if ....

The if-else syntax must evaluate to a single expression. Something like num //= 2 or num -=1 is an entire statement, not an expression.

It has already been mentioned that you cannot perform a -= assignment in an operand of an expression, so it is not allowed either in such a conditional expression.
Note that you can optimise your code with the following observations:

Every 1-bit in the number's binary representation will need a corresponding minus-1 operation at some point

Every digit in the number's binary representation will eventually become a 0 digit, which all -- except the last one -- will need to be shifted away by a division-by-2 operation.


This leads to this code:
    def numberOfSteps(self, num: int) -> int:
        return max(num.bit_length() + num.bit_count() - 1, 0)

The max(, 0) wrapper serves to deal with the boundary case where num is 0. In that case .bit_count() will evaluate to 0, and so we need to adapt the final result to 0.

As @jonrsharpe mentioned there is no such a syntax construct. Moreover using common if / else will make your code more readable:
if not num % 2:
    num //= 2
else:
    num -= 1

You can also consider using num % 2 == 0 instead of not num % 2 to make your intentions more explicit.

num //= 2 and num -= 1 are statements, but conditional expressions require expressions (as it must evaluate to a value).
You could use assignment expressions wrapped in parentheses like so
(num := num // 2) if not num%2 else (num := num - 1)

but it is better to just use a standard if statement instead
if num % 2: num -= 1
else: num //= 2

or assign a conditional result to num.
num = num - 1 if num % 2 else num // 2

